# Why Jquery toggle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code on my index.php (index.php has it's own CSS file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").click(function() {
    var destino = document.formu0.list0.value
    var lista = "#listaP"+destino;
    $(lista).toggle(2000)
 });
});
</script>
```

And on another file, I have an php code that generates html code, menuP is the tag containing(display: none; padding-right: 10px;):

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<div id="lista0">';
echo '<form name="formu0">';
echo '<select size="10" name="list0">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cidades); $i++)
    echo '<option value="'.($i).'">'.$cidades[$i][0].'</option>';
echo '</select></form></div></td>';

echo '<menuP>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cidades); $i++)
{
    $k = 0;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div id="listaP'.$i.'">';
    echo '<form name="formuP'.$i.'">';
    echo '<select size="6" name="listP'.$i.'">';
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($resultsA); $j++)
        if ($resultsA[$j][0] == $cidades[$i][0])
        {
            if(count($resultsA[$j])==6)
                $tipo = 'Onibus';
            else
                $tipo = 'Aviao';
            echo '<option value="'.($k).'">'.'Preco R$: '.$resultsA[$j][1].' Tipo: '. $tipo .'</option>';
            $k++;
        }
    echo '</select></form></div></td>';
}
echo '</menuP>';
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? The code doesn't work despite "destino" and "lista" being with the correct values, and testing it with a blank website, it works. The basic function would be to hide/show the specific list of data that corresponds to the city the user clicked.

Comment: Please post output HTML, I'm sure you'll get more help...

Comment: -1, not because the question is especially bad, but because you include lots of irrelevant PHP code. Try to keep the code you post down to what's relevant to the question at hand. This is not a serverside problem at all so HTML and JS is the only things needed.

Answer (score 0):

"menuP is the tag containing(display: none; padding-right: 10px;)"

There's your problem. Toggling a descendant element's visibility will have no effect if the ancestor element is not visible.

Here's a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/32eXp/

You'll need to find a way to make the `<menuP>` element visible.

Comment: Maybe using an actually valid HTML tag would help the DOM see it?

Comment: The DOM sees it and displays it as an inline tag. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/32eXp/1/ for an example. Turning off `display: none;` for `menuP` is what's needed.

Comment: menuP isn't an child of lista0. However I got it to work, turns out I really need to learn Jquery and CSS asap :P
In any case, thanks :)